# Unable to revert previous commits in Git for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and I am new to Git. The master repository is on Visual Studio Online. I have made some local commits and some changes which I have not committed to my local repository. I have never pushed any commit. Now I wish to push few commits to the main repository. Also I want to revert the other commits. When I try to revert them then a message comes up which is "Cannot revert the commit because there are uncommitted changes. Commit or undo your changes before reverting the commit again." How can I undo the changes? I have made so many commits. I want to revert some of them only.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Team Explorer, ensure you are on the `Changes` tab.
2. Right-click the top folder, and click `Undo Changes...`.
3. When prompted, click `Yes` to continue.

---

You can also use standard Git commands. From a command line (e.g. Git Bash), do:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```